# How does MyBatis deal with data type when insert and update?

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, mybatis

I have been using `String` when INSERT and UPDATE no matter what data types the data in my oracle database are. Util I try to compare some ID data with `NUMBER` data type with `String` did I realize that something I forget which is the data types of the data in the database. But It seems my code work fine except retrieving data from the database and doing some comparisons. So how does MyBatis deal with data type when insert and update?

Comment: I would think that the string/number transformation back and forth are done by the JDBC driver, not MyBatis. That could be sketchy, since at some point you may be forced to upgrade the JDBC driver, and all of a sudden the whole application will stop working. Use proper types (integer, long, LocalDate, boolean, etc.) and sleep well at night.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Another question: Is there any problem that may arises if I set MyBatis SQL mapping `resultType="string"` but the SQL data type is `NUMBER`?

Comment: I would guess that transforming integer-like values to string is straightforward and shouldn't cause any issue. For fixed or floating point values that could produce some inconsistencies, though.